# Why does "&& true" added to a constraint make a function template a better overload?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following two overloads of a function template `foo`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(T) requires std::integral<T> {
    std::cout << "foo requires integral\n";
}

template <typename T>
int foo(T) requires std::integral<T> && true {
    std::cout << "foo requires integral and true\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note the difference between the two constraints: the second has an extra `&& true`.

Intuitively speaking, `true` is redundant in a conjunction (since `X && true` is just `X`). However, it looks like this makes a semantic difference, as `foo(42)` would [call the second overload](https://godbolt.org/z/q6xTf5f9T).

Why is this the case? Specifically, why is the second function template a better overload?

Comment: It's "more specialized".  There are more requirements, so it's narrower, so it's "better".

Comment: @NathanOliver Even though the requirement itself is superfluous?

Comment: So, would adding `&& !false` make it even better?

Comment: AFAIK, the standard doesn't really care what it does, just that there are more requirements.

Comment: I think conjunctions by definition add more specificity to the requirement and thus is preferred over less specific ones if both match

Comment: @AdrianMole Looks like the answer is no: https://godbolt.org/z/j6hG98WEv

Comment: It falls out of the rules. There's not really motivation to add a special case for this.

Comment: @ph3rin The real reason that this call is ambiguous is that the two `true`s do not come from the same source location, hence neither subsumes the other. If you instead define `template<typename T> concept mytrue = true` and compare `integral<T>` vs `integral<T> && mytrue<T>` vs `integral<T> && mytrue<T> && (!false)`, the call will no longer be ambiguous. It is hence better to treat the `true` in `&& true` as an anonymous concept that always evaluates to `true` and has a unique source location.

Comment: The reason that an overload defined with `requires integral<T> && true` and an overload defined with `requires integral<T> && true && (!false)` make the call ambiguous is exactly the same reason why an overload defined with `requires is_integral_v<T>` and one with `requires is_integral_v<T> && true` would make the call ambiguous.

Comment: @WeijunZhou You are indeed correct, but I think you made some typos here since my question is an example what is **not ambiguous**. For references, here is an example that **is ambiguous** because of the reason you have mentioned: https://godbolt.org/z/Tbj4xc8Yr

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. When I said *ambiguous* I was referring to your earlier comment 
 which links to https://godbolt.org/z/j6hG98WEv. I was not referring to the snippet in the main question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per [[temp.constr.order]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.order), particularly [[temp.constr.order]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.order#1) and [[temp.constr.order]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.order#3)

> /1 A constraint `P` subsumes a constraint `Q` if and only if, [...] [ Example: Let A and B be atomic constraints. **The constraint `A ∧ B` subsumes `A`**, but `A` does not subsume `A ∧ B`. The constraint `A` subsumes `A ∨ B`, but `A ∨ B` does not subsume `A`. Also note that every constraint subsumes itself. — end example ]
>
> /3 A declaration `D1` **is at least as constrained** as a declaration `D2` if
>
> - (3.1) `D1` and `D2` **are both constrained declarations** and `D1`'s **associated constraints subsume those of** `D2`; or
> - (3.2) D2 has no associated constraints.

if we consider `A` as `std::integral<T>` and `B` as `true`; then:

- `A ∧ B` which is `std::integral<T> && true` subsumes `A`, which is `std::integral<T>`,

meaning that for the following declarations:

```
// Denote D1
template <typename T>
void foo(T) requires std::integral<T> && true;

// Denote D2
template <typename T>
void foo(T) requires std::integral<T>;
```

the associated constraints of `D1` subsume those of `D2`, and thus `D1` *is at least as constrained* as `D2`. Meanwhile the reverse does not hold, and `D2` *is not at least as constrained* as `D1`. This means, as per [[temp.constr.order]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.order#4)

> A declaration `D1` is more constrained than another declaration `D2` when `D1` is at least as constrained as `D2`, and `D2` is not at least as constrained as `D1`.

that the declaration `D1` *is more constrained* than declaration `D2`, and `D1` is subsequently chosen as the best match by overload resolution, as per [[temp.func.order]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.func.order#2):

> Partial ordering selects which of two function templates is more specialized than the other by transforming each template in turn (see next paragraph) and performing template argument deduction using the function type. The deduction process determines whether one of the templates is more specialized than the other. If so, the more specialized template is the one chosen by the partial ordering process. If both deductions succeed, the partial ordering **selects the more constrained template** (if one exists) as determined below.

Comment: So `true` on itself is an atomic constraint?

Comment: @Meowmere Yes, as there is no _requirement_ that the expression (say `E`) that constitutes [an atomic constraint](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.atomic#1) need to involve template parameters, only that it _may_ (_"[...] from the template parameters that appear within `E`"_ - in the case of `E` being `true`: none). See e.g. [the example of \[temp.constr.normal\]/1.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.normal#1.4.example-1) which describes `true` (`E2` there) as an empty mapping but a normal form nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

The constraint `std::integral<T> && true` subsumes `std::integral<T>` and therefore "wins" according to the partial ordering of constraints rules.

To check if constraint A subsumes B ([[temp.constr.order]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.constr.order)):

1. Both constraints are brought to a *disjunctive normal form*. This means all `||` are "expanded" to their independent form.

2. Then each *disjunctive clause* is split into [*atomic clauses*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.constr.atomic) (smallest `&&`-parts).

3. The meaning of atomic clauses themselves isn't compared, they are only compared for equality.

If constraint A contains all the atomic clauses of B and some more, then A subsumes B.

See [Example 1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.constr.order#example-1):

> *[Example 1:* Let A and B be atomic constraints. **The constraint A ∧ B subsumes A**, but A does not subsume A ∧ B. The constraint A subsumes A ∨ B, but A ∨ B does not subsume A. Also note that every constraint subsumes itself. — *end example]*

So it doesn't matter that the additional clause is a no-op, it's there in A but not in B, and that's all there is to it really.

Answer (score 1):

> Intuitively speaking, true is redundant in a conjunction

Indeed!  In the interest of adopting standard-speak, let's say your specializations are *functionally equivalent*.

> Why is the second function template a better overload?

Surprise!  *It isn't.*

The standard explicitly references your `&& true` constraint in an example of a program that is **ill-formed, no diagnostic required**.

[[13.5.2.3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#temp.constr.atomic-example-2)

> *a program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, when the meaning of the program depends on whether two constructs are equivalent, and they are functionally equivalent but not equivalent.*
>
> *[Example 2:*
>
> ```
> template <unsigned N> void f2()
>   requires Add1<2 * N>;
> template <unsigned N> int f2()
>   requires Add1<N * 2> && true;
> void h2() {
>   f2<0>();          // ill-formed, no diagnostic required:
>                     // requires determination of subsumption between atomic constraints that are
>                     // functionally equivalent but not equivalent
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example]*

Comment: You made a good point, but the confusing thing here is that `2 * N` and `N * 2` are functionally equivalent, but not equivalent, yet there is another example in the standard that uses `&& true` but did not mention any illl-form NDR (in fact, it comments "*Ok*"). Specifically, [this one](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.op#5).

Comment: @Meowmere good reference there!  I am not sure what to make of that.  I'll let this answer _just sit here_ for now.

Answer (score -2):

Second specialization is picked because C++ uses partial ordering algorithm for picking the generic function specialization.

*Partial ordering selects which of two function templates is more specialized than the other by transforming
each template in turn (see next paragraph) and performing template argument deduction using the function
type. The deduction process determines whether one of the templates is more specialized than the other.
If so, the more specialized template is the one chosen by the partial ordering process. **If both deductions
succeed, the partial ordering selects the more constrained template (if one exists)** as determined below.*

*13.5.4 Partial ordering by constraints*

*13.7.6.2 Partial ordering of function templates*

of C++ 20 final working draft which can be found here:
http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You can't just say "the answer is called X, you'll find it in this 1500+ page document" and call that an answer.

Comment: The answer to the question is *C++ uses partial ordering algorithm for picking the generic function specialization.*

Comment: No, it isn't. You need to explain what it is about that algorithm which causes this *specific* effect. Otherwise, your answer is incomplete.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer by quoting the standard.

Comment: And what makes the needless `&& true` version "more constrained" than the other one?

Comment: Just the pure existance of it.

Comment: "*Just the pure existance of it*" I see nothing in your answer which indicates that this would be true. Indeed, you never actually say that adding `&& true` makes it "more constrained".